# render price or owned based on 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have 2 arrays: `all_games` and `owned_games`.
I want to display all the games, and next to each game:
- if it's `owned` display owned
- if it's `not owned` display a price

**Current Output:**
 1 - 10.00
  2 - 10.00
  3 - 10.00

**DesiredOutput:**
 1 - Owned
  2 - Owned
  3 - 10.00

[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/muscaiu/pen/PKxVpw?editors=0010)

```
render() {
    let renderPriceSection
    let renderOwned = <span>Owned</span>
    let renderPrice = <span>10.00</span>
    let all_games = [{ "game_id": 1 }, { "game_id": 2 }, { "game_id": 3 }]
    let owned_games = [{ "game_id": 1 }, { "game_id": 2 }]

    all_games.map((game) => {
        owned_games.map((owned_game) => {
            owned_game.game_id === game.game_id ?
                renderPriceSection = renderOwned :
                renderPriceSection = renderPrice
        })
    })
    return (
        <div>
          {all_games.map((game)=>{
          return(
            <p>
              {game.game_id} - {renderPriceSection}
            </p>                
          )                
        })}                
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: No error, just the wrong output. Check the CODEPEN.

Comment: the problem is, that you have to stop checking once you found out that you own a game. otherwise it will render the price again

Comment: you're also using the same renderPriceSection for ALL games

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not setting the `renderPriceSection` to the game. You are keeping it in a single variable. So every games will have the same `renderPriceSection`.

You should add a property to each game and keep their price section

```
all_games.map((game) => {
    game.renderPriceSection = owned_games.find((owned_game) => owned_game.game_id === game.game_id) !== undefined ? renderOwned : renderPrice;
})
```

Then in the return statement you get this property from the game

```
return (
    <div>
      {all_games.map((game)=>{
      return(
        <p>
          {game.game_id} - {game.renderPriceSection}
        </p>                
      )                
    })}                
    </div>
)
```

See the edited [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEaNYq?editors=0011)

Answer (score 2):

1. Inner `.map` `owned_games.map` is useless
2. You do not need to do several iterations in order to set `renderPriceSection`, you can do it in one `.map` and avoid using useless variables

```js
const OWNED = 'owned';
const PRICE = '10.00';

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    let all_games   = [{ "game_id": 1 }, { "game_id": 2 }, { "game_id": 3 }]
    let owned_games = [{ "game_id": 1 }, { "game_id": 2 }]

    const isOwnGame = (gameId) => (
      owned_games.some(({ game_id }) => game_id === gameId)
    );

    const games = all_games.map(({ game_id }) => {
      return (
        <p key={game_id}>
          {game_id} - <span> { isOwnGame(game_id) ? OWNED : PRICE } </span>
        </p>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div>
        { games }                
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Note:** In this case better to change data structure for `owned_games` in order to avoid high complexity, would be better to use Hash, like so

```
let all_games   = [{ "game_id": 1 }, { "game_id": 2 }, { "game_id": 3 }]
let owned_games_ids = { 1: { ... },  2: { ... } };

const isOwnGame = (gameId) => {
  return typeof owned_games_ids[gameId] !== 'undefined';
};
```